# sql query for grouping column into row

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have table like this

```
Name        Slot
 A           1
 A           2
 A           3
 B           1
 B           2
```

and I want to make query so the result is like

```
Name    slot1    slot2    slot3    slot4
 A        Y        Y        Y       N
 B        Y        Y        N       N
```

or

```
A:1,2,3
B:1,2
```

I have try to use `GROUP BY` but I dont know how to get the slot number.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
  max(case when slot = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end) slot1,
  max(case when slot = 2 then 'Y' else 'N' end) slot2,
  max(case when slot = 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end) slot3,
  max(case when slot = 4 then 'Y' else 'N' end) slot4
from tablename
group by name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/zfRaeRs21jhBTgQ284WYe/1).
Results:

```
| name | slot1 | slot2 | slot3 | slot4 |
| ---- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| A    | Y     | Y     | Y     | N     |
| B    | Y     | Y     | N     | N     |
```

And for the 2nd case use `group_concat()`:

```
select concat(name, ':', group_concat(slot)) col
from tablename
group by name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejvUMCGb1U3DfdU9pbZnhm/0).
Results:

```
| col     |
| ------- |
| A:1,2,3 |
| B:1,2   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` :

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(Slot)
FROM table t
GROUP BY name;
```